# How to validate all constraints in a MariaDB database for existing data after import?

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys, constraints

I imported data into a MariaDB database while foreign key constraint checks were disabled. Those checks were enabled afterwards. However, some data in the database seems to be corrupt in the sense that the foreign key constraints are not satisfied.

I tried to use the `mysqlcheck` tool to verify all tables, but this does not produce any error output. Also running `CHECK TABLE someTable` does not show any errors or warnings.
Still I can manually show data not being correct, for example by performing a query:

`select count(*) from some_table where id not in (select id from related_table)`

where some_table has a foreign key constraint to related_table by `id`.

How do I fix this?